# Custom taxonomy huge list not loading properly in select box

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have custom post type "Book" and custom taxonomy "Author" associated with books.
I have used remove_meta_box to hide default UI for taxonomy, because it was like tags where you can add multiple tags and select multiple tags for post.

What i want was that only one author is associated with book. So i used add_meta_box to create select box for authors where admin can select one author from list.

Now authors list has grown beyond 3000 authors and select box does not seems to load it properly.....

I don't want to go back to original UI like tags....

Is there any thing where i could give search, pagination and add functionality(add only one taxonomy) in meta box....

This is code i am using..

```
remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-book_author', 'book', 'normal');

add_meta_box('custom-taxonomy-author-dropdown','Author','author_dropdowns_box','book','side','high');

function author_dropdowns_box( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field('custom-author-dropdown', 'author-dropdown-nonce');
    $terms = get_terms( 'book_author', 'hide_empty=0');
    $object_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'book_author', array('fields'=>'ids'));

     echo "Author:";
    echo "<select id='bauthor' name='bauthor[]'>";
    echo "<option value='0'>None</option>";
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

            if ( in_array($term->term_id, $object_terms) ) {
                $parent_id = $term->term_id;
                echo "<option value='{$term->term_id}' selected='selected'>{$term->name}</option>";
            } else {
                echo "<option value='{$term->term_id}'>{$term->name}</option>";
            }

    }
    echo "</select><br />";

}

add_action('save_post','save_my_custom_taxonomy');
```

Comment: can you show us you meta box code? I  had a similar problem and i fixed it by "caching the dropdown".

Answer (score 1):

Just like i commented , this will create the dropdown if it doesn't exists  and will save it in the database

```
    remove_meta_box('tagsdiv-book_author', 'book', 'normal');

add_meta_box('custom-taxonomy-author-dropdown','Author','author_dropdowns_box','book','side','high');

function author_dropdowns_box( $post ) {
    wp_nonce_field('custom-author-dropdown', 'author-dropdown-nonce');

    echo "Author:";
    echo "<select id='bauthor' name='bauthor[]'>";
    echo "<option value='0'>None</option>";
    $options = get_option('bauthor_dropdown');
    if ($option !== false){
        echo $options;
    }else{
        $options = '';
        $terms = get_terms( 'book_author', 'hide_empty=0');
        $object_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'book_author', array('fields'=>'ids'));
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                if ( in_array($term->term_id, $object_terms) ) {
                    $parent_id = $term->term_id;
                    $options .= "<option value='".$term->term_id."' selected='selected'>".$term->name."</option>";
                } else {
                    $options .= "<option value='".$term->term_id."'>".$term->name."</option>";
                }

        }
        update_option('bauthor_dropdown',$options);
        echo $options;
    }
    echo "</select><br />";

}

add_action('save_post','save_my_custom_taxonomy');
```

and all that is left is to clear the list when you add/edit/delete a term of that taxonomy:

```
//clear the list when a new term is created: or edited
add_action('edit_book_author','clear_on_add',10,2);
add_action('created_book_author','clear_on_add',10,2);
function clear_on_add($term_id, $tt_id){
    delete_option('bauthor_dropdown');
}

//clear the list when a term is deleted:
add_action('delete_term', 'clear_on_delete',10,3);
function clear_on_delete($term, $tt_id, $taxonomy){
    if ($taxonomy == "book_author"){
        delete_option('bauthor_dropdown');
    }
}
```